# Escape semicolon, double quotes and backslashes for curl

Tags: linux, string, curl, escaping

What is the proper way to send this `,./'; '[]}{":?><|\\` as form-data value in curl. I'm doing this

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://postman-echo.com/post' \
--form 'more=",./'\'';[]}{\":?><|\\\\'"
```

right now and it gives different result, apparently only 2 backslashes in the response which is supposed to be 4 in total 
[Response snippet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt5L8.png)

Comment: Put the whole thing to send inside `\"` and `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Apparently this was the problem with my fish shell which was escaping the trailing double quotes. When i ran the same request on bash it was successful.

Answer (score -1):

probably a shell is interpreting your cmd-line and each `\\` pair gets reduced to a single `\`

(revision, even more explicit) :

using echo to show results,

```
echo more=",./';[]}{\":?><|\\\\\\\\"
```

adjust if needed, then copy the `more="..."` part to your curl cmd-line